# CSS excluding children from style

Tags: html, css, html-lists

```css
ol li{
color: blue;
}
ol ol li {
color:black;
}
ol ol {
 list-style: upper-alpha;
```

```html
<ol>
  <b><li>Topic 1</li></b>
    <ol>
      <li> Sub Topic 1</li>
      <li> Sub Topic 2</li>
      <li> Sub Topic 3</li>
    </ol>
    <b><li>Topic 2</li></b>
    <b><li>Topic 3</li></b>
    <ol>
      <li>Sub Topic 1</li>
      <li>Sub Topic 2</li>
      <li>Sub Topic 3</li>
    </ol>
</ol>
```

Simple question I hope. The first level of an `<ol>` is always a heading.  Trying to style

```
ol li {
font-size:larger;
}
```

without changing ol ol li or other children.

So much thanks!

Edit:

HTML structure is

```
<ol>
<b><li>Topic</li></b>
<ol>
<li> Sub Topic 1 </li>
<li> Sub Topic 2 </li>
</ol>
<b><li>Topic 2</li></b>
</ol>
```

The goal is to remove the need for the bold tags.

Comment: It would depends on the structure of the site. What else do you have there? Why can't you add some classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking: "The first level of an `ol` is always a heading" - Do you really mean a heading like `<h1>`, <`h2>` etc., or do you mean that you want to apply a special styling to the first `<li>` *inside*  every `<ol>` tag ?

In the latter case, you can use a `:first-child` selector, like

```
ol > li:first-child {
  font-size:larger;
}
```

In case you want to apply a special styling to *any* first child if every `<ol>` tag, you can use the general `*` selector, combined with `:first-child`

```
ol > *:first-child {
  font-size:larger;
}
```

(Although I doubt that anything else than an `li` as a direct child of an `ol` would be valid HTML)

---

Addition after edit of question:

Since your `ol` will be inside some other element, you can use the following selector to adess only *direct* ("first-level") children of the `ol`. (I applied a class to the parent element and used that in the selector)

```css
.parent>ol>li {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ol>
    <li>Topic</li>
    <ol>
      <li> Sub Topic 1 </li>
      <li> Sub Topic 2 </li>
    </ol>
    <li>Topic 2</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I made an edit to the question.  Thank you for your help.  The solution made the first child of the order list and the first child of the nested ordered list both larger.  I am trying to get each li of the ol and none of the li of the ol that is nested in another ol.

Answer (score 0):

If it is inside a certain container always (for example .container), you can do so:

```
.container > ol > li {
font-size:larger;
}
```

Here it would only apply it to direct child ol and that only to direct child of that.